# How to execute python Popen with pipes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to run next code (on python3.4):

```
p1 = Popen(['screen', '-la'], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(['tail', '-n', '+2'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p3 = Popen(['head', '-n', '-2'], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p4 = Popen(['awk', '"{print $1}"'], stdin=p3.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p5 = Popen(['xargs', '-I{}', 'screen', '-S', '{}', '-X', 'quit'], stdin=p4.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
p2.stdout.close()
p3.stdout.close()
p4.stdout.close()
out = p5.communicate[0]
print(out)
```

and I receive an error:

```
p5.communicate[0]
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"communicate" is a method, not a property, can you try this instead:

```
out = p5.communicate()[0]
```